# Execute command for a specific output of a command

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I am interested in executing a certain command every time **any** program I run outputs "segmentation fault". Basically I have a bash script that writes the timestamp in a log file and do some other stuff as well.

For my coursework, one module requests that we do this for each exercise. Sure I can make a script and run each program from within the script, but I was wondering if there is any way of generalizing this.

What I want is really for *any program* that is *run by an user*, if output contains "segmentation fault" execute command

Comment: smells like homework

Comment: "create a signal handler for SIGSEGV"  is a coding question and not an Ubuntu question

Comment: @EduardoCola Well, it's not. It's just that I have a module with a bunch of exercises and I'm too lazy to change the script to fit each one. Plus I'm quite interested in this in case I'll ever need to log stuff easily based on output, without modifying the program

Comment: @Rinzwind "segmentation fault" was just to give context. What I'd like to do is set some string (for example segfault - maybe I'm doing java and I'm interested in a particular error occurring).
I know exception handling is usually done from within programs - but I'm looking for something that is more system-wide and targets similar behaviour from multiple programs.
Indeed (thanks), for SIGSEGV in particular, a handler will work - but how about other outputs (that are not necessarily a well-defined signal)?

Comment: You should know that "Segmentation fault" is not printed by the command, but [by the shell](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/257616/70524). So no utility that captures the program's output will get that. Correspondingly, often the return code of a program that dies of SIGSEGV maybe 139.

Comment: @muru Fair enough, what I meant was the output of a program run in a shell (so obviously the program returns something and that is interpreted or displayed by the shell accordingly).
So what I'm interested in is: given a program being run in the shell, if "string" is contained in the console output, execute command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A program segfaulting's exit status is set to `139` by Bash (so this applies at least to programs which didn't define a handler for SIGSEV receiving a SIGSEV while running in Bash: it should fit your usage case):

```bsh
$ cat foo.c 
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char *ptr = NULL;
    *ptr = 'a';
    return 0;
}
$ gcc foo.c -o foo
$ ./foo
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
$ echo $?
139
```

You could set `PROMPT_COMMAND` to something like this in `~/.bashrc`:

```bsh
PROMPT_COMMAND='[ $? -eq 139 ] && printf "SIGSEV received\n"'
```

Changing `printf "SIGSEV received\n"` to the command you wish to run.

```bsh
$ PROMPT_COMMAND='[ $? -eq 139 ] && printf "SIGSEV received\n"'
$ printf '\n'

$ ./foo
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
SIGSEV received
```

Comment: Technically, none of that is due it being in C, or using glibc. The shell sets the exit status of a process killed by a signal to be 128+(numeric value of signal), and SIGSEGV is 11. (See http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/252006/70524)

Comment: @muru That sounds right. Misconceptions. But then I guess it's safe to assume Bash + SIGSEV = exit status `139` (unless handled)?

Comment: Yes, I'd say so.